# .net application not writing to hkey_local_machine in registry

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB .NET application and I am currently trying to get it to write to the local_machine registry however I can't seem to make it work correctly.
I am trying to create the key in one application and read it in another.
Here is my code to create

```
Dim regKey As RegistryKey
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE", True)
regKey.CreateSubKey("appName")
regKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\appName", True)
regKey.SetValue("Serial", "regValue")
regKey.Close()
```

I do have it running with administrator rights and it runs the code without throwing any exceptions.

A few interesting things it does:

-The application that creates it seems to be able to read it correctly however if I try to delete it is says it doesn't exist.

-I can't see it at all in regedit

-The application that reads it can't access it. If I create the key manually in regedit it can read it fine and can read other applications keys

I assume I am missing something but can't see what.
Thanks

Also if I create the key in the current_user it works fine and appears in regedit normally

Comment: I suppose a case of [Registry redirection at work](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Indeed it was, It was showing in regedit under Wow6432Node like that link said.
Turned out that application that creates it was using .NET 4.5 and the app to read it was running .NET 4.0.

Put them both on 4.0 and now it is writing the keys in the correct location

Thanks

Comment: It has nothing to do with the .NET version, the bitness of the process is the one that matters.  Project > Properties > Compile > Target CPU setting.

Comment: Didn't think changing the .NET version would have fixed it but that is all I did and it worked perfectly after that. After hours of it not working.